# Get text length inside cxGrid's memo column

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have changed the property of a column in the cxGrid to 'Memo' and
set its `MaxLength` to 150.

I would like to have a label displaying countdown to maxlengt as I type.

I tried :

```
cxlabel1.caption := 'Chars left : ' + inttostr(cxGrid1DBTableView1MYFIELD.Properties.MaxLenght - Length(cxGrid1DBTableView1MYFIELD.Text));
```

but delphi says maxlenght is unavailable thou it exists in the memo field properties.

Can it be done?.

Comment: Is it a bound grid or an unbound grid?

Comment: it is a bound grid.

Comment: I reappraised the question. I do not want to use calculated field but a label.

Comment: `MaxLength` (you have a typo in your code) is imlemented in `TcxMemoProperties` class, so you have to cast column's `Properties` to this class. Also column does not have `Text` property. If this code is in `OnChange` evet handler then cast `Sender` to `TcxMemo` and get it's `Text`.

Comment: @BrakNicku  Not sure I follow you ..   The fields property is changed to memo and that has MaxLenght. ?? Last part I dont get.

Comment: The first sentence of your question says that you have changed it, so now it's  TcxMemoProperties.